# What is Virtualbox's "vboxdrv" module?

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel, virtualbox

I have a tainted kernel and at least currently `journalctl -k | grep taint` points to the specific module:

```
localhost.localdomain kernel: vboxdrv: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
localhost.localdomain kernel: vboxdrv: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

I've only installed software from the official Fedora repositories (never from Copr). Is the module non-free and can Virtualbox ship proprietary components? I've  installed 'guest additions' for some machines via Virtualbox, if this matters:

[image: guest additions in Virtualbox]

---

I can move to other virtualization software if these issues can be expected under Linux.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the module non-free and can Virtualbox ship proprietary components?

VirtualBox is released under GPL2 (except for certain features like USB and disk encryption) however Linux kernel developers are [not fans](https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/10/6/317) of the VirtualBox kernel modules due to a large number of issues thus `vboxdrv` "taints" the kernel.

The patch was merged over a decade ago, however no one is willing to revert it.

> I can move to other virtualization software if these issues can be expected under Linux.

As far as I can see you've got zero issues. You can use QEMU/KVM all you want but they are miles worse in terms of features and usability.

> What is Virtualbox's "vboxdrv" module?

This driver is required to enable fast [hardware] virtualization. Virtualization can be done purely in software but it will be catastrophically slower.

Comment: "As far as I can see you've got zero issues." - I've had some system freezes, journactl messages appear to cut off just before the OS becomes unresponsive. I assumed that a tainted kernel is seen as a serious problem.

Comment: *"I assumed that a tainted kernel is seen as a **serious** problem."* - what made you assume so? Have you tried Googling? System freezes might be caused by overcommiting memory and your VM has nothing to with that - RAM provisioning does. If you have 4GB of RAM, yet you allocate 2GB for your VM and run multiple applications on your host at the same time you may get system freezes and crashes.

Comment: Oftentimes people in their quest for Open Sourcedness of their software stack make my blood boil. Not only you seemingly barely understand what you're actually running, you most likely don't even understand what hardware you're using and how it works. Your computer boots into the closed source software, that's called EFI. Your CPU contains (yeah, AMD has PSP in case you believe Intel and NVIDIA are evil) closed source software built-in, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: I've been using VirtualBox for over a decade. I've had exactly zero issues caused by it.

Comment: I have 32GB of DDR4 RAM and Ryzen 5700G. VMs at most used 12GB (8GB for Windows 11 and some Linux distro running) I'd guess. I'm aware that the kernel has shipped with binary blobs since 1996. I don't think that Google is a good resource, it's better to point users directly to reliable sources.